# PHP changing timestamp format

Tags: php, timestamp

So I tried to convert a time string to "X seconds ago" and stucked with this issue:

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 <a href="#Profile"><class="profilep" id="postp" /></a>
 <ul>
 <li class="userName"></li>
 <li class="distance"></li>
 </ul>
 <div class="time">
 '.
 $eventTime = $row['time'];
 $age = time() - strtotime($eventTime);
 echo $age "ago"
 .'
 </div></div>
 <p align="justify"></p>
 </div>
 </article>';
```

The loop loads not only $age, but also $row['time']. I wonder why it's happening and how to fix it? Thank you for your time and for helping me to learn.

Comment: Just removed the `` ` `` to let the code be formatted as a code block.

Answer (score 0):

The concatenation seems all wrong. Do the calculation first, then create the output. And next time, please include proper code.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $eventTime = $row['time'];
    $age = time() - strtotime($eventTime);
    // Here is probably something missing.
    echo '
                <a href="#Profile"><[what tag should go here?] class="profilep" id="postp" /></a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="userName"></li>
                    <li class="distance"></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="time">' . $age . ' seconds ago</div>
            </div>
            <p align="justify"></p>
        </div>
    </article>';
}
```

Comment: thanks for an advice. I'm still learning. So every answer is valuable for me.